# Ubuntu often freezes when I make videos in Chrome fullscreen. How can I fix this?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, freeze, youtube

With Ubuntu 15.10 running on 64 bit Intel i7 with Intel graphics hardware, I find that Unity freezes very often when I make videos played in Chrome fullscreen. The operating system does not freeze and I can hear the video playing, but the graphics freezes. I can attempt to run `unity --replace` in another tty, but this doesn't help, usually resulting in an interface missing major graphical elements.

What could be causing this and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Hi, could you fix the problem?